# c++ defining object type via enum

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

I have this basic setup:

```
enum{
    BASE,
    PRIMITIVE,
    ...
};

class IUnknown{
public:
    bool inline is(int type){return inv_type == type;}
private:
    enum {inv_type = BASE};
};

class Primitive: public IUnkown{
private:
    enum {inv_type = PRIMITIVE};
};
```

My problem is that I would want to be able to call is on a Primitive instance and have it return true when type is equal to the value in the enum I have declared in the Primitive class.

The only solution I have found is to declare the '**is**' function as virtual and have a copy in every subclass, but I wondered if it would be possible to somehow redefine the enum and have the is function in IUnkown take the value from there

Comment: I suspect you're not applying polymorphism correctly to your problem. You shouldn't end up with this situation to begin with. Virtual binding will determine the behavior of your object for each defined virtual method without the need to check the object type through is().

Comment: I agree with Robert, it seems like you're trying to manually implement dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: You might want to both avoid using the name and research the actual use of `IUnknown`, it's the foundation of a good chunk of polymorphic code in use.

Comment: I'm trying to make an interpreter for a self made dynamically typed language, IUnknown is a base class for a templated Invariant that will have to be able to store any sort of data. The is function lets me know what type of data it is storing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your IUnknown class define a protected constructor (which would then have to be called from each derived class).  It would take one of the enum values and store it.  The stored value would then be compared against in the is() method.

If you don't like this, and prefer to add a virtual is() method to IUnknown,  but don't want to have to define it in every derived class, you could do this:

```
template <int Tinv_type>
class IUnknownT : public IUnknown{
public:
    virtual bool is(int type){return inv_type == type;}
protected:
    enum {inv_type = Tinv_type};
};

class Primitive: public IUnknownT<PRIMITIVE>{
};
```

Comment: I think you missed the fact that I wrote IUnknownT which derives from IUnknown (which itself would be unchanged from the OP's version except that the is() method would be pure virtual).

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s by themselves don't take up storage space because they're just lists of acceptable values for an `enum` variable. You have to have some runtime storage going on for a virtual function to actually work with the runtime type of the object. I would just use an `int` or something:

```
enum{
    BASE,
    PRIMITIVE,
    ...
};

class IUnknown{
public:
    bool is(int type) const {return inv_type == type;}

protected:
    IUnknown(int type) : inv_type(type) { }

private:
    const int inv_type;
};

class Primitive: public IUnkown{
private:
    Primitive() : IUnknown(PRIMITIVE) { }
};
```

Comment: (And it should be `const`, too.)

Comment: @KerrekSB ah yeah, forgot to `const` it, thanks. I'm a forgetful person :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not go all out and use strings instead of enums.

```
const char * baseStr = "base";
const char * derived1Str = "derived1";
const char * derived2Str = "derived2";

class base
{
public:
    virtual bool is(const char * str)
    {
        return strcmp(baseStr, str) ? false : true;
    }
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    bool is(const char * str)
    {
        if ( strcmp(derived1Str, str) )
            return base::iA(str);

        return true;
    }
};

class derived2 : public derived1
{
public:
    bool is(const char * str)
    {
        if ( strcmp(derived2Str, str) )
            return derived1::is(str);

        return true;
    }
};
```

This has the benefit that this

```
base * b = new derived2();
bool is = b->isA(baseStr);
```

sets `is` to `true`.